# Spring Data Rest custom argument Resolver

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

So i am trying to add a custom argument resolver to my Spring-Data-Rest project.
I am devolping a multi-tenant application, and need to filter data based on a users tenant-id.
So i wrote a simple annotation and ArgumentResolver to query my tenant repository and inject a tenant Object as Parameter on some needed Methods:

Handler:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TenantInjector implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    private final TenantStore tenantStore;

    private final TenantRepository tenantRepository;


    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        if(! methodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(InjectTenant.class)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {

        return tenantRepository.findById(tenantStore.getId()).get();
    }

}
```

This handler queries the tenantRepository to find the current tenant by its Id, which is set when the incoming requests security token is parsed.

To register the handler, i do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherContext implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    private final TenantStore tenantStore;


    private final TenantRepository tenantRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DispatcherContext(TenantStore tenantStore, TenantRepository tenantRepository) {
        this.tenantStore = tenantStore;
        this.tenantRepository= tenantRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
            List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new TenantInjector(tenantStore, tenantRepository));
    }
}
```

This works nice as long as the corrensponding Controller is annotated with either @Controller or @RestController

As the @RepositoryRestController has an other context, this configuration is ignored. How can I add the same ArgumentResolver to the Spring-Data-Rest configuration?

It might be an option to just switch the annotations, but i would like to rather stick with this approche, as links get generated by spring-data-rest.

Has anyone stumble over this to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue could be that you registered your custom argument resolver in your `WebMvcConfigurer`. Spring Data Rest seems to work in a different context, so you have to register your custom argument resolver in your `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`.

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    public RepositoryConfiguration(ApplicationContext context, ObjectFactory<ConversionService> conversionService)
    {
        super(context, conversionService);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> defaultMethodArgumentResolvers()
    {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = 
            new ArrayList<>(super.defaultMethodArgumentResolvers());
        resolvers.add(new TenantInjector(tenantStore, tenantRepository));
        return resolvers;
    }
}
```

Answer inspired by: https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver/issues/6#issuecomment-111952898

Comment: Once you override `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` you effectively turn off autoconfiguration. In order to keep all configurability of things like json serialization etc you have to also define and create an equivalent to this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/157b71b333473c2633b17362df1be83d6f9eaaed/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.java#L37

Answer (score 0):

@HugoLeao really nails it with the answer above, but one thing that happens as a side effect of defining a custom `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` is that all the configuration for things like json serialization become ineffective, because `RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration` gets disabled. I had to do this in order to keep it working

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    
    public RepositoryConfiguration(ApplicationContext context, ObjectFactory<ConversionService> conversionService) {
        super(context, conversionService);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> defaultMethodArgumentResolvers() {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>(super.defaultMethodArgumentResolvers());
        resolvers.add(new TenantInjector(tenantStore, tenantRepository));
        return resolvers;
    }

    // Add this to keep configurability 
    @Component
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(RepositoryRestProperties.class)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    class SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

        private final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;
        private final RepositoryRestProperties properties;

        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
            this.properties.applyTo(config);
        }

        @Override
        public void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapperBuilder.configure(objectMapper);
        }
    }
}
```

This comes from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/157b71b333473c2633b17362df1be83d6f9eaaed/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer.java#L37